# Code in website templates accessing database... bad?

Tags: python, mako

I'm using Python, Mako templates and Beaker cache. Caching is controlled by blocks inside the templates:

```
<%block cached="True" cache_key="${id, day, privilege}">
...
</%block>
```

When I'm caching something that involves a complex database query, I perform that query inside the cached block so it won't be executed if the block is found in cache:

```
<%block cached="True" cache_key="${id, day, privilege}">
<%
data = db_interface.do_that_query()
%>
...
</%block>
```

For everything that's not cached, I query the data before calling the template, and pass the data in rather than a database handle. It feels messy querying the database in both the business logic and the templates, but is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With no other knowledge of your set-up:

If your `<%block />` contains the logic for conditionally determining if the cached data is available and issuing the query then surely the initial query (by the 'business logic') is redundant.

Simply call the template without the initial query and you should be able to scrap the 'business logic' code.